# box-orient in both direction?

Tags: html, css

What I am [trying to do here](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/aUSWE/) is to make the `<div>`s (9 in my demo) to arrange like `井` (a 3x3 grid). My approach is to use the flexible box layout to make them spread evenly across the whole area.

```
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
     ...
    <div>9</div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
#container > div {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50px;
}
```

However, this will make them line up in a single axis. I can change the orientation to `vertical` or `horizontal`, but not both. What is a better (and working) way to achieve this with only CSS? The  `float: left` trick won't work here because the size of the container will vary.

Comment: Can you make 3 sets of 3 divs, or does the size of each vary too much in both dimensions?

Comment: @Joe - I can make 3 sets of divs, but I would prefer a way to do this without creating unnecessary divs wrappers.

Comment: This seems a bit pointless if the container has a set width

Comment: @ExplosionPills - Its width is not really fixed in the actual case, it's only fixed in the demo.

Comment: @ExplosionPills - even if they were set widths (and it seems obvious from the question they're not really), I'd rather use flexbox than just force widths if I were him since it may make development easier in the future to have a flexbox grid set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually looking at the wrong specification.  The 2009 specification is being phased out in favor of the CR draft from Sept. 2012.  To make a 3x3 grid with flexbox, you need to enable wrapping.  The property from the 2009 draft for that was called `box-lines`, but the last remaining browser that follows that spec (Firefox) never implemented it.

http://jsfiddle.net/aUSWE/1/ (prefixes not included)

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    resize: both;
    overflow:auto;
}
#container > div {
    flex: 1 1 33%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This probably isn't going to stay here permanently, but it might help:  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6

Comment: Does Chrome 18 support `display: -webkit-flex`? Since I don't have Chrome 18 I can't test it myself.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox According to caniuse, 23+ supports the new candidate recommendation.

Comment: @cimmanon - I download Chrome 19 and it does not work. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @Derek Chrome 17-20 follows the March 2012 spec (the same one IE10 uses), which would be `display: -webkit-flexbox`.

Comment: @cimmanon - I have tried `flexbox`, but all the `div` just squish together on one line, and I already put in `-webkit-box-lines: multiple`. Any ideas?

Comment: If Chrome isn't honoring `-webkit-flex-flow`, `-webkit-flex-direction`, or `-webkit-box-lines`, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.  I hadn't run across anything stating that Chrome doesn't support multiple lines.

Comment: @cimmanon - I seperated them into different lines and now it works, however now it requires excessive JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-flexbox-20110322/#flex-order

It seems to me like the w3 standard for flexbox explicitly requires them to be either horizontal (LR/RL) or vertical (TB/BT), so I don't believe you can explicitly call for a 3x3 grid.  As noted in the comments, the simplest solution seems to be three vertical flexbox divs with 3 horizontal flexbox divs inside of them (or the inverse).  Unnecessary divs, indeed, but what else is CSS about? :)

You might look into grid-layout (http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-grid-layout-20110407/ ) since that seems like it's the grid cousin of flexbox.  (Of course, that would be if you're designing solely for IE 10... http://caniuse.com/css-grid )

Comment: The grid layout is really interesting... only if it can be used on other browsers...

Comment: Sadly both FF and Webkit have been implementing it since late 2011... not sure what's taking so long, it can't be that complicated?  Looks like it's going to be another annoying -prefix-thing, too =/

Comment: Seems like I have to stick with the dividing-them-into-rows method then.